# Cisco 851W - recovering from corrupt configuration

Tags: networking, cisco, router

While learning how to use my Cisco 851W router, I downloaded a configuration script with preconfigured settings. I ran this from the router and now I can no longer boot up and get to a command prompt.

I have tried holding the reset button while turning the router back on, but I guess there is no valid file in flash because it continues loading the config from NVRAM.

Here is the output during bootup. At the last line, it freezes and I can no longer do anything. Any ideas how to recover from this?

```
System Bootstrap, Version 12.3(8r)YI4, RELEASE SOFTWARE Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport Copyright (c) 2006 by cisco Systems, Inc.

C850 series (Board ID: 4-149) platform with 65536 Kbytes of main memory

Booting flash:/c850-advsecurityk9-mz.124-4.T8.bin Self decompressing the image :
#################################################################### [OK]

              Restricted Rights Legend

Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is subject to restrictions as set forth in subparagraph (c) of the Commercial Computer Software - Restricted Rights clause at FAR sec. 52.227-19 and subparagraph (c) (1) (ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer Software clause at DFARS sec. 252.227-7013.

           cisco Systems, Inc.
           170 West Tasman Drive
           San Jose, California 95134-1706



Cisco IOS Software, C850 Software (C850-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version
12.4(4)T8, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3) Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport Copyright (c) 1986-2007 by Cisco Systems, Inc. Compiled Sat 11-Aug-07 03:29 by khuie Image text-base: 0x8002008C, data-base: 0x811EED90


This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption. Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at: http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to export@cisco.com.

Cisco 851W (MPC8272) processor (revision 0x200) with 59392K/6144K bytes of memory. Processor board ID FHK1151267B MPC8272 CPU Rev: Part Number 0xC, Mask Number 0x10 5 FastEthernet interfaces 1 802.11 Radio 128K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory. 20480K bytes of processor board System flash (Intel Strataflash)



Press RETURN to get started!


*Mar  1 00:00:05.919: %VPN_HW-6-INFO_LOC: Crypto engine: onboard 0  State changed to: Initialized
*Mar  1 00:00:05.923: %VPN_HW-6-INFO_LOC: Crypto engine: onboard 0  State changed to: Enabled sslinit fn

*Mar  1 00:00:08.367: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:08.367: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet4, changed state to down
*Mar  1 00:00:08.855: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to administratively down
*Mar  1 00:00:08.899: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from memory by console
*Aug 22 12:53:04.363: %SYS-5-RESTART: System restarted -- Cisco IOS Software, C850 Software (C850-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version 12.4(4)T8, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3) Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport Copyright (c) 1986-2007 by Cisco Systems, Inc. Compiled Sat 11-Aug-07 03:29 by khuie
*Aug 22 12:53:04.363: %SNMP-5-COLDSTART: SNMP agent on host yourname is undergoing a cold start
*Aug 22 12:53:04.383: %SSH-5-ENABLED: SSH 1.99 has been enabled
*Aug 22 12:53:04.423: %CRYPTO-6-ISAKMP_ON_OFF: ISAKMP is OFF
*Aug 22 12:53:04.423: %CRYPTO-6-ISAKMP_ON_OFF: ISAKMP is OFF
*Aug 22 12:53:04.623: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0, changed state to up
*Aug 22 12:53:05.031: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to down
*Aug 22 12:53:05.751: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet4, changed state to administratively down
*Aug 22 12:53:05.959: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet3, changed state to up
*Aug 22 12:53:05.963: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet2, changed state to up
*Aug 22 12:53:05.967: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet1, changed state to up
*Aug 22 12:53:05.971: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0, changed state to up
*Aug 22 12:53:06.127: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Virtual-Dot11Radio0, changed state to administratively down
*Aug 22 12:53:06.959: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet3, changed state to down
*Aug 22 12:53:06.963: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet2, changed state to down
*Aug 22 12:53:06.967: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet1, changed state to down
*Aug 22 12:53:06.971: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0, changed state to down
*Aug 22 12:53:07.127: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Virtual-Dot11Radio0, changed state to down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding that Putty was not allowing me to see the login screen. I installed SecureCRT and the login prompt showed up right away. Weird since I'm using the exact same settings on both programs (9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit).

Answer (score 3):

Use the password recovery method explained here, but instead of recovering the password, delete the startup configuration. http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/800/850/software/configuration/guide/857sg_bk.pdf